# Mr. Mouse Goes Shopping

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, lateral-thinking, story

> I had a perfect preface to this story, I swear, but now it escapes me. Oh well! It mustn't matter much, must it?

**'T**was the night before Black Friday and all through the house, not a creature was stirring, except, of course, for Mr. Mouse, and Mrs. Mouse, and all of their teenage mouse-pups that were out god-knows-where having snuck out through the secret, gnawed-out holes in their bedroom walls.
Mrs. mouse gave her shopping list to Mr. Mouse for a Helter Skelter midnight sale run and off he ran into the night.

His first stop was to "Whole Foods" (the Mouse Family's favorite store, of course), which, surprisingly, didn't exclusively sell things like bagels, donuts, cherrios and swiss cheese. He asked an attendant for help.
"Hi! I believe you have this on sale." He showed her Mrs. Mouse's list and pointed to one item in particular.
"Oh, OK, you want one with a string commin' off of it, yeah?"
"Yes, oh, yes! It is the kind shown here, that will help Mother Mouse get to sleep. The relaxing kind."

One down, three to go!

Now, something for Mr. Mouse (from Santa, of course!). Mr. Mouse's model train hobby had been getting quite out of hand as of late, but there was one more item he needed to make it feel complete. The hobby store was sure to have what he needed.
"Hello, sir, might you help me?" he inquired of the shop keeper. "I need accessories for an 'overhead' train, bridges and supports and such, suitable for an accurate depiction of the train service that runs in the Greater Chicago Metropolitan area. Can you help?"

Two down, two to go.

"Now, some music for my teenagers," he thought. "What sort of music do kids like in this year of our lord, 2018?" He tapped his little mouse foot and frowned as he thought.
"Oh, I know! Obscure 1960's jazz will do the trick! I'll go and pick up a copy of *Let's Misbehave* and call that a simply perfect gift. The kids'll just *love* it."

Last one... one that the whole family could enjoy. You see, the Mouse family's dear grandfather clock was broken, and had been for some time. It was an antique, that has been handed down for over 20 generations. That's over *five whole human years!* But this year, the family heirloom would finally be fixed. Mr. Mouse stopped at the town's best horologist's shop and picked up a large, arrowed hand, the last piece needed to get it running smoothly again.

Now the question is, of course:

> What was the oh-so-pertinent preface that I was trying to think of for this story?
>
> `__ __ __ __`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe the preface you were looking for is

> [TL;DR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TL%3BDR)

Because

> Mother Mouse was getting **tea**, Mr. Mouse was building a model of the **L** train, the kids were punished with an album by Billy **Dee** Williams, and the grandfather clock was finally getting its **hour** hand fixed.

Comment: Little help: rot13(juvpu vf gur ynetr, neebjrq unaq ba n pybpx?)

Comment: @Chowzen Edited, is that correct?

Comment: That's it. You probably wish I'd remembered to write this in the beginning, huh? :)

Comment: @Chowzen I kept reading because I thought there would be cheese in the end!